# Link between phase noise, frequency noise, and line width? -- and how to go from dBc/Hz to linewidth

Tags: noise

So I'm trying to measure the integrated linewidth of a laser using the self-heterodyne method, as per figure 5 of "Narrow Linewidth Laser Phase Noise Characterization Methods for Coherent Transmission System Applications".

My basic steps are as follows - measure the phase noise, translate that to frequency noise, integrate that into linewidth.

So when I measure the SSB phase noise on my ESA, I get the result in dBc/Hz, which indicates that it's been normalized to the total power (hence the dBc) and that it's also been normalized to the bandwidth (hence the inverse Hertz).

In my particular case I'm measuring the linewidth of a laser using the self heterodyne method, so I need to include a term which accounts for the finite length in delay line between the two paths, but that's simple. Just a simple (1 / 4*sin^2(pi*f*tau)) factor, as per eq 14 of the paper I mentioned earlier.

At this point, my normalized phase noise matches well with specs given by the company, so I think this is all correct.

Next, it seems like since I want to convert to linewidth, I need to use an intermediary step and convert to frequency noise.

So, I say that S_f = f^2 * S_phi, then integrate S_f (the frequency noise), over the bounds of interest, and get the linewidth.

Unfortunately, this result is wildly off, which means I'm doing something wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this help? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/38227/58729

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, I already read that and totally understand. Maybe it's the linewidth issue (the integration over the frequency noise) that doesn't make as much sense to me?